# How to debug a Gooey GUI python program

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey) to convert a simple set of argparse arguments in GUI elements.  My IDE is pycharm.  What I can't figure out is now to debug the program when the GUI is being called.

Below is a simple program that uses Gooey.

```
import argparse
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser

def get_args():
    parser = GooeyParser(description='Gooey Test',
                         formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('a')
    parser.add_argument('b')

    results = parser.parse_args()

    return results


def addnumbers(a,b):
    c = a + b
    return c

@Gooey(advanced=True)
def main():
    results = get_args()
    a = float(results.a)
    b = float(results.b)
    c = addnumbers(a, b)

    return c


if __name__ == "__main__":
   c = main()
   print(c)
```

For example, if I place a breakpoint on a line 17 of the program (c = a + b) I would expect the program to stop there and allow me to inspect the values of variables that have been executed to that point.  However, the program continues to run to completion.

Any thought would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you running in debug mode? I mean shift+f9 instead of shift+f10?

Comment: yup ... hit the little bug rather then the play symbol in the pycharm gui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out debugging doesn't work when running Gooey.

https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/issues/144

The author suggests turning off the decorator while debugging.